# how to do warranty lookup of HPE HDDs?

Tags: hard-drive, hp-proliant, warranty, hpe

I have had this problem a lot, and I was wondering if anyone knows the way to do this. WHAT information do I need to get my warranty lookup for HP(E) Harddrives for proliant servers. so. if you go to this webpage:

http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/wc/public/home you can enter 3 pieces of information:

A) Product serial number.
B) Product number (this one is only needed if (A) above is not enough). 
C) Country of purchase.

on the harddrive itself I see about 13 different numbers that could be Serial numbers or Product numbers, and nothing that seem to reflect country. (I have numbered them 1-13 on the screen shot below, please refer to that number if you can help me).

My HDD was purchased from a Norwegian Company, that has its storage/mother company in England, and I know they purchase these all over Europe if not the world.

does anyone has any good way for me to choose what number goes where?

[image: example HDD (well SSD actually)]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because such questions are prone to change, dob't have anything to do with system administration and are also completely arbitrary. This question should be directed to HPE. Get your phone and call them.

Comment: @Daniel It's a valid question. The OP doesn't seem to know how HP support works, but warranty and parts replacements are part of the job... (_as I prepare to go replace a failed drive at the datacenter..._)

Comment: @ewwhite Warranty and replacements are part of the job, yes. Figuring out which parts of the label should be entered on which field at the vendor's website... no, I don't think that's an appropriate question for ServerFault. The only thing to do is to actually talk to the vendor.

Comment: @JennyD HP's support model and process is unfamiliar to some. In the end, nothing on the drive's label is actually important beyond the spare part label on the front of the drive. There's nothing to enter on the website. But I could see how people coming from Dell or whitebox/Supermicro environments wouldn't know that. The OP seems reluctant to just contact HP, but at least this gives some direction.

Comment: thanks for your comments. Initially I could actually  not find the contact details for HPE. I did in the end find the contact number, and managed to call them. my question I feel is valid.. as there IS a place to enter serial number to check if this particular HDD is in warranty or not. BUT as it turns out This drive did NOT excist in their system. and the HP People are checking in to that for me. I am sure that a lot of people in the future will have this question, and will wonder what to do, and I think this post will help them find that information they need at that time.

Comment: @Sverre In my previous job, we used HP servers and software extensively. One of the great advantages to leaving that place is that I no longer need to use their horrible horrible heap of junk they call a support web site. My blood pressure has dropped significantly. I'm glad you got in touch with the right people, though I still don't believe that a question which can only be answered with "call the vendor" belongs here - but I am only one person and do not own the site :-)

Comment: thanks for feedback and understanding @JennyD, I agree that HPE has some very bad parts when it comes to finding out what you need to find out. and it is really sad that the only good solution is to call a human... I agree, I wish this case could have a better answer, but I am sure other come accross the same problem... where HPE ask for a serial number, and the product (HDD in this case) has several serial numbers on multiple stickers... so which one to use. (and in this case, even with correct serial, their system still does not work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S/N = Serial Number

P/N = Product Number

So in this case, it's 1 and 8. There is a second product number (4) for some reason, but the one you need is the one with the barcode. The barcode is there so you can quickly scan SN and PN.

Comment: I agree with you, that is seems logical, but it does not show up on the list. it says "The information you provided does not match our records. Please review your entry again and make any necessary edits or contact HPE for more assistance. "

Comment: HPE has a support chat.. but I can not even find the hdd on the list of products to open the chat window, so I can not even ask them!

Comment: @Sverre Disks are consumables. Logistically, it does not make sense for HPE to track and catalog the warranty of so many parts; some of which are refurbished, repairs, purchased at different times, etc. That's why the warranty tends to follow the server chassis. If you need a replacement, just call HP.

Comment: I would if I could find a phone number for them

Comment: @Sverre [Find your country. Contact HPE](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/hpe/contact/ww-contact-us.html).

Comment: I have contacted HPE now, andthe drive above is NOT on their list.. he is still investigating it. thanks for your help.

Comment: I think it's a safe bet that the other product number (4) is the actual drive manufacturer's (Samsung, in this case) product number for the drive itself, as opposed the the product number assigned by HPE.

Answer (score 3):

The warranty on HP servers and equipment is tied to the server chassis, which has a 3-year manufacturer warranty.

Basically, if it's [inside the server](https://community.hpe.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-ML-DL-SL/Warranty-on-Proliant-hard-drives/td-p/6753808) and has an HP part number, it's typically covered.

There's no need to provide individual hard drive information beyond the *Spare Part* number to HP support.

But for this particular drive, the [standard warranty is 3 years](http://www8.hp.com/emea_middle_east/en/products/oas/product-detail.html?oid=6974224).

Comment: The HDD/SSD are purchased separately from the server, and they fail constantly... so need to check them.

Comment: It doesn't matter when they were purchased. They're covered by your chassis warranty. HP will never ask you for the disk serial number; just the _Spare Part_ number on the HP label with the hologram.

Comment: so, if I have an older server (maybe 3  years old), in a remote location. the tech on site, noticed a failed drive. took it out and replaced it with a space I had on location. he took a photo of the disk, and asked me... in warranty or should I hammer it and throw away? HP Does  have a warranty look up tool, that I know has worked in the past on hdds, but I can not find this one, and also other.. what do I do? the HDD  has nothing to do with the server it is in, they were bought at different times.

Comment: HP doesn't care about the disks. Your support is tied to your chassis. You can look at the disk and see its manufacture date... 3 years from that date or purchase date is the technical expiration... but it really doesn't matter.

Comment: sorry, but does not make sense! we sometimes buy new HDD for older servers.. the servers warratny expired  years ago, but the disks still have a 3 year warranty!

Comment: HP will replace the disks if you want hem to. Just give them the Spare Part number. If you have more questions about this, _please_ contact HP.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, another drive that I could not figure out WAS indeed in warranty (for another 3 months), and it will be replaced by HPE, they asked about the server serial (like you said), but later said they did not need it, the hard-drive serial was enough. so, I guess we are both correct. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

HPE's warranty is mainly link to the server. If additional part is installed in the server,it covers with the server warranty or part warranty, what comes later.

eg. Server has 3 year warranty. User installed a separately purchased HDD after one year, which the hard drive has 3 year warranty. If the disk failed customer has two ways to get the warranty replacement.

1) for the next two years, report the issue to HPE support with the serial number+part number of the server and the spare part number[13] (SPN/replace with HP spare) of the hard drive.

2) after the second year (when the server warranty expires), report the issue to the HPE support with the serial number[11]+part number[12] of the hard drive and the spare part number[13] of the hard drive.

**Note**: You don't have to remove the hard drive from the bay, to get the spare part number of the hard drive. Its marked on the sticker, pasted on top of the handle of the hard drive. It is the number next to the capacity mark of the sticker. In older servers it has the format of xxxyyy-001 and in newer servers it has the format of xxxyyy. For all the other parts part number has the format of xxxyyy-001

The warranty link https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/wc/public/home only provide the warranty information of the server. Need to select the country of purchased and serial/Part number of the server. Though this is a late answer, this might help some.